# Angular ngx-spinner not showing

Tags: angular, spinner

I need to show the spinner till the data is fetch from the httpclient. But the spinner is not showing.

I just need to show spinner or loader until the data comes from API so user can see the data is loading. Is there any problem in my `.html` ?.

It's showing when I'm filtering data but not showing when the page is loading .

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ApiService } from 'app/services/api/api.service';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
    })
    export class HomeComponent {

      clientData: Observable<any>;
      data: any  = []; 
      status: any = [];
      countunsettled: any;
      countsettled: any;
      sums: any;

      policy_id:Set = new Set();

       constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private api:ApiService, public httpClient: HttpClient, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { 

       this.getClaims();
      }

      userFilter: any = { policy_id:'', claim_no:'', member_name:'', status:'', company_id: ''};

    openDeal(deletecontent,x){
       this.selectedDeal = x;
        this.dealModal= this.modalService.open(deletecontent, x);
        this.dealModal.result.then(r=>{
        }, err=> console.log(err))
    }

     getClaims(){
           this.spinner.show();

     if(this.userFilter.company_id){
       let url = 'xyz.com.pk'+this.userFilter.company_id;
     }else{
       let url = xyz.com.pk.php?offset=0&limit=100';

      }

     this.clientData = this.httpClient.get(url).
     subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.spinner.hide();

       this.data = data.records;
       this.data.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id));

     var status = 'settled';
     var status2 = 'submitted';

     var countsettled = this.data.filter((obj) => obj.status === status).length;
     var countunsettled = this.data.filter((obj) => obj.status === status2).length;

     console.log(countsettled);
     this.countsettled = countsettled;
     console.log(countunsettled);
     this.countunsettled = countunsettled;

     const sum1 = this.data.filter(item => item.status === 'settled')
                     .reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.approved_value), 0);
                     console.log(sum1);
                     this.sum1 = sum1;

     const sum2 = this.data.filter(item => item.status === 'submitted')
                     .reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.approved_value), 0);
                     console.log(sum2);
                     this.sum2 = sum2
         }
      }
    }
```

**html template:**

```html
<ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>
```

it's not showing any error and also not showing the spinner.

Comment: share your full code of component.ts

Comment: attach the full code. but now when im filtering data its showing the spinner . but when page is loading its not showing spinner.

Comment: what do you actually mean by page loading? do you mean the initial home page load of your angular project

Comment: when im login then this home.component open . i need the loader here until the data fetched the spinner shows on page

Answer (score 19):

I faced this issue when I upgraded from 11 to 13. 
Here are the steps you need to take:

1. In `package.json` file:

```
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "ngx-spinner": "^13.1.1",
    ...
```

Or click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner#installation) for installation.

2. In `angular.json` file:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-circus.css", // This wasn't required in version 11.
              "src/styles.scss" 
            ],
```

3. In `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
...
          imports: [
                    MatModule,
                    NgxSpinnerModule,
                    CommonModule
          ],
          exports: [
                    MatModule,
                    NgxSpinnerModule,
...
schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] // This is new to version 13 as well,
```

4. In `home.component.ts` file:

```
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
...
constructor (private spinnerService: NgxSpinnerService, ...){...}
...
//wherever show needed:
this.spinnerService.show();

//wherever you want to hide the spinner:
this.spinnerService.hide();
```

5. In the `html` file:

```
...
<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)" size="large" color="#fff" type="ball-circus" [fullScreen] = "true"></ngx-spinner>
...
```

The older versions have slightly different setup. Since I upgraded from  version 11 to 13, the spinner stopped working. It took me a day to find out this setup that works for version 13.

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes inclusion in styles in angular.json is necessary. I didn't need to use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA. Also make sure you restart your app after you add the style in angular.json

Comment: Thank you. This saved me hours of investigation.

Answer (score 6):

You need to call spinner.show() in ngAfterViewInit;
if not in here, this.spinner is undefined

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void { this.spinner.show(); }
```

Comment: Is there a way to call the spinner from a click-based action?

Answer (score 3):

I had to make changes in this part of [@abbas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6650896/abbas-hosseini) solution

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ...
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-circus.css", // This wasn't required in version 11.
          "src/styles.scss" 
        ],
```

Adding CSS file's path to `styles` didn't work for me.
so, I had to import this in `styles.scss` like this

```
@import "~ngx-spinner/animations/ball-circus.css";
```

Answer (score 2):

If after the setup you see an overlay but not the animation itself, restart the application. The animation should appear after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [Example in the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-spinner-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Fuser-list%2Fuser-list.component.ts)

In your typescript file

```
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";
constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show();

    setTimeout(() => {
         this.spinner.hide();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue and the simple solution is whatever animation type you use in html, make sure you have added CSS for same in angular.json

For eg:
HTML:

```
<ngx-spinner
bdColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)"
size="medium"
color="#fff"
type="line-spin-fade" // type
[fullScreen]="false"
><p style="color: white">Loading...</p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

angular.json / project.json(NX)

```
"node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/line-spin-fade.css" //use same type css
```

Answer (score 0):

Make to use the correct version of ngx-spinner based on your angular version.
If you have angular 15 but you've installed the latest version of ngx-spinner, then you'll get an error.

Here's all ngx-spinner versions:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner?activeTab=versions

Install via:

```
npm i ngx-spinner@<YOUR_VERSION_HERE>
```